# Why do I get 405 Post Method not allowed Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-405

I have a post method in my routes file, which is also visible in php artisan route:list

```
Route::post('endpoint/Bu','MenuController@endpoint')->name('endpoint');
```

The route is also added as an exception in the VerifyCsrfToken page

```
protected $except = [          
    'https://website.nl/endpoint/Bu'     
];
```

When I perform a POST request via Postman, it gives me 405 Method not allowed.

The controller requests a bearer token

```
$token = $request->bearerToken();
```

Why am I getting this error?

I tried adding the url of the page to Csrf exception. I tried to clear the cache of the routes. I am expecting a status 200, instead I get 405 Method not allowed.

The Postman configuration log:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImVsbHltZWQyMDI1In0.eyJpc3MiOiI5NS4xNzAuNjguMTAxIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg4NDU0NDAyLCJvcmctaWQuc3lzdGVtIjoibG9jYWwiLCJvcmctaWQudmFsdWUiOiIxNjg2MTI0ODIzIiwidXNlci1pZC5zeXN0ZW0iOiJsb2NhbCIsInVzZXItaWQudmFsdWUiOiJodWlzYXJ0c0BlbGx5bWVkLm5sIiwiY29udGV4dC54a...-PaS17pUSLTqa9xYcwr4vfmC9zJ_Q
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.3
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 50ad582f-87ab-4221-b9a3-b908257745e1
Host: website.nl
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlBFOXd4WkU2cE9IVU4zcFBWNU5maXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUU5ieGVMWlNJb2plVnkyUjdGdzRDclAwT1o2eWs2aFQvV1FpaDVWZ0svQjFqNFhUR1NWaHlFclp0N3NyL3BBYnc1SGNGUGV5ektkTWR5dExLVFVBTjRsRWoveHhrWHc5SzZpZERrcTc5V295M1pUZU...; labplusarts_session=eyJpdiI6InA3SXN3YXBaZTFRVk90d2tKbFB1ZGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSzBjUEtVWm5seHJ3T0JtTmttMEM1cXJ4c3hETk5yQUxJbkFWSFFGaWtUaFd0VlR5c29TSFVhZXJ2N1hiTHVweDhOUlcyL01RUGE4SDZhMyt2U3F4NU1pR3dlMm1zREtNendlY2JXTTY1NkJOdFV...
 
HTTP/1.1 301
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 04 Jul 2023 08:15:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://website.nl/endpoint/Bu
```

Comment: You'd have to show us the configuration of the postman request, at the very least. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue

Comment: It's a simple POST request to the endpoint url with an error 405

Comment: That doesn't tell us anything useful though. Perhaps there is something odd, or you made a small mistake. Or maybe it's something else entirely. The point is, we don't know, and until we do we cannot usefully help you because we can't see exactly what you've done, and can't rule in or out any issues with that aspect of the program. Merely describing it to us is no good. Hence why I linked you to those articles...did you read them? I don't think you had time to absorb them properly before you replied less than 5 minutes later.

Comment: Added the configuration log

Comment: `Location: https://website/endpoint/Bu` I feel the `.nl` part is missing from your postman request endpoint. Also try `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: That was a mistake on my part in trying to replace my url. I already tried route:clear and cache clear